# Cannot read property 'members' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix ='!';
require("dotenv").config();




bot.on('message' , message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!check')) {

    const list = bot.guilds.cache.get("708789786579828736");

    list.guild.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));

    if (member) {
      for (user of list.members) {
        console.log(user[1].username);
      }
    }

  }
})
```

Says Cannot read property 'members' of undefined. How do I define it? Keep in mind I'm trying to reference all the members of a server and do an action to them such as adding a role.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will try out each one of these to see if I get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix ='!';
require("dotenv").config();




bot.on('message' , message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!check')) {

    const list = bot.guilds.cache.get("708789786579828736");

    //list.guild.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));

    if (list.guild.members) {
      for (user of list.guild.members) {
        console.log("--user--");
        console.log(user);
        console.log("--user[1].username--");
        console.log(user[1].username);
      }
    }

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by your `if` statement & `for` loop not being the `forEach()` loop.

```js
list.guild.members.forEach(member => { 

console.log(member.user.username));

    if (member) {
      for (user of list.members) {
        console.log(user[1].username);
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about discord.js, but If I was you I'd first try to debug this by outputting your `list` object after that call to `bot.guilds.cache.get("708789786579828736");`
Then, you'll be able to see if `list` is initialized properly and contains all the fields and collections of objects you're trying to access.
Then, depending on what exact line is causing the error, ask yourself these questions :

- Does `list.guild` exist when calling `list.guild.members`?
- Does `list` exist for this expression : `for (user of list.members) {...}`?

Also, as Syntle said in his answer, your line containing `if(member){...}` is not part of the `forEach` loop you used to enumerate and log all members of `list.guild.members`; that might be another problem of your program.

Good luck!